# phpmyadmin server variables and session values

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, utf8mb4, server-variables

I'm going to use `utf8mb4`. Also some of my variables must be utf8mb4 that mentioned [here](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4). I set them from phpmyadmin `Variables` menu. But some of changes to utf8mb4 but it's **session value** is still `uft8`.

[image]

And when I run this command:

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE  'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE  'collation%'
```

That show me utf8, **not utf8mb4**. Any idea?

**EDIT:** When I set the a variable to `utf8`, session value disapear.

Comment: You may have set the global version of the variable, but not the session one.

Comment: @Shadow But I can't edit the session value. Just able to edit variable.

Comment: Yes, you can, using the `set` statement. See its documentation in the MySQL manual.

Comment: @Shadow I found this syntax: `SET SESSION sql_mode = 'TRADITIONAL';` but the same result!

Comment: Why do you want to set the sql mode? Change those variables that you are interested in.

Comment: @Shadow because as I mentioned here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/153720/mysql-unable-to-store-emoji-in-utf8mb4-collation I have problem with uft8mb4. And please check edit part.

Comment: 1) Pls do not expect me to check all your other previous posts to be able to answer your question. Include everything that is relevant for this question in this particular post. 2) No idea what the edit means.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To establish permanent changes to these, or any other, "Variables":

1. Edit `my.cnf`
2. restart the server (mysqld)
3. (obviously) you will then need to log in again.

The flow:

- When the server starts, my.cnf is used to override builtin defaults; the combination becomes the `GLOBAL VARIABLES`.
- When you connect, the global variables are used to initialize the `SESSION VARIABLES`; these are used by your connection.
- If you do a `SET`, it will modify only your session variable.  The value will be lost when the connection closes.

Another note on utf8mb4...  Most client software (php, phpmyadmin, etc) has a way of setting the `CHARACTER SET` and `COLLATION` for the connection.  *This* is when you should establish that "the bytes in the client are "UTF-8" encoded.  (The outside world calls it UTF-8; MySQL calls the same thing utf8mb4.)

Update:  MySQL 8.0 has an optional way to make the setting of `GLOBAL VARIABLES` "persist", thereby bypassing step 2 (restart).

Comment: Thank you. Very nice description. The main problem is that I can't find `my.cnf` file. I searched a lot on the net  but no results. (I'm in localhost and using xampp)

Comment: And somewhere I've seen that this file should be in `/etc/my.cnf` but where  `etc` is located?

Comment: What Operating System?  It could be called `my.ini`.